# Procedure not updating the data in the database

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

this is my asp code:

```
<body>
     <form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">

    <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Id" InsertVisible="False">
                <EditItemTemplate> 
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("id") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate> 
                <ItemTemplate> 
                    <asp:Label ID="lblId" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("id") %>'></asp:Label> 
                </ItemTemplate> 
            </asp:TemplateField> 

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="firstname">
                <EditItemTemplate> 
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("firstname") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate> 
                <ItemTemplate> 
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("firstname") %>'></asp:Label> 
                </ItemTemplate> 
            </asp:TemplateField> 
            </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

</div>
</form>
```

and this is my vb code:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data

Partial Class testt
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Public connectionString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("TestConnectionString").ConnectionString
    Public cn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        If cn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            cn.Open()
        End If
        Dim command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("selecttest", cn)
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(command)
        da.Fill(ds, "testtt")
        dt = ds.Tables(0)
        GridView1.DataSource = dt
        If Not IsPostBack Then
            GridView1.DataBind()
        End If
        If cn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            cn.Close()
        End If
    End Sub
    Protected Sub GridView1_RowUpdating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewUpdateEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowUpdating
        Dim strPersonID As String = DirectCast(GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("TextBox1"), TextBox).Text
        Dim strLastName As String = DirectCast(GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("TextBox2"), TextBox).Text
        Try
            Dim command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("updatetest", cn)
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pid", strPersonID)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pfirstname", strLastName)
            If cn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                cn.Open()
            End If
            command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("1 row updated")
            If cn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                cn.Close()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
    Public Sub GridView1_RowEditing(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewEditEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowEditing
        GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex
        If Not IsPostBack Then
            GridView1.DataBind()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

1- the columns in the grid is duplicated which means that I'm getting the selected data from the stored procedure and the data binded in the template fields in new columns so instead of getting just 2 columns I'm getting 4 having the same data so how can i fix this?

2-no errors in the rowupdating event everything is working fine but the data is not being updated in the database. Note that the stored procedure is working fine in SQL..
it may be cause because of the duplicated columns mentioned before...

any help??

thank you !

Comment: It is not a ASP.NET MVC 4.

Comment: set autogeneratecolumns="false" for problem number 1